# How to set a custom user-agent for mail.app on macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: mac, email, exchange, user-agent

I am trying to access my emails on a Microsoft Exchange Server. I could do it with the mail.app on the mac as well as on the iPhone. Seems like the access via mail.app on macOS has been blocked recently from outside the intranet while mail.app on iPhone still works.

Is there any way to access the server via mail.app on macOS? I.e. changing the user agent string etc.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: What do you mean by"access has been blocked"? Are there any errors on Outlook for Mac? You may refer to this article regarding connection issue : 
 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-can-t-connect-to-my-exchange-account-372b793f-e8d3-4aed-a3a9-dbfbfad97c6d

Comment: According to my research, It seems we cannot change the User-Agent in the HTTP header.

Comment: I am using the mail.app on macOS Mojave. As soon as I try to check emails from outside the corporate network the following error message appears: "Can't connect to the account 'Exchange'. Unable to verify account name or password."

Comment: Your IT department likely has a secure mechanism for you to check via you phone, but only allows access from your Mac when you're at work. Contact said department and see whether they offer VPN accounts.

Comment: I already contacted them. There is a citrix solution which is cumbersome and does not support the usage of macs mail.app